# Keras Deep Learning and Financial Returns

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, finance, quantitative-finance

I am experiencing with Tensorflow via the Keras library and before diving into predicting uncertainty, I thought it might be a good idea to predict something certain. Therefore, I tried to predict weekly returns using daily price level data. My input shape looks like this: (1000, 5, 2), i.e. 1000 matrices of the form:

```
Stock A   Stock B
 110       100
 95        101
 90        100  
 89        99
 100       110
```

For `Stock A` the price at `day t=0`is `100`, `95` at `t-1` and `100` at `t-5`. Thus, the weekly return for  `Stock A` would be `110/100=10%`and `-10%` for `Stock B`. Because I focus on only predicting Stock As return for now, my y for this input matrix would just be the scalar `0.01`. Furthermore, I want to make it a classification problem and thus make a one-hot encoded vector via `to_categorical` with 1 if the y is above 5%, 2 if it is below -5% and 0 if it is in between. Hence my classification output for the aforementioned matrix would be:

```
0 1 0
```

To simplify: I want my model to learn to calculate returns, i.e. divide the first value in the input matrix by the last value of the input matrix for stock A and ignore the input for stock B. This would give the y. It is just a practice task for me before I get to more difficult tasks and the model should achieve a loss of zero because there is no uncertainty. What model do you propose to do that? I tried the following and it does not converge at all. Training and validation weights are  calculated via `compute_sample_weight('balanced', )`.

```
Earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=150, mode='min', verbose=1, min_delta=0.0002, restore_best_weights=True) 
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('nn', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min', save_weights_only=False)
Plateau = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5, patience=30, verbose=1)
optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=True)

input_ = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, 1, 5, 2)) 

model = LocallyConnected2D(16, kernel_size=(5, 1), padding='valid', data_format="channels_first")(input_)
model = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(model)
model = Dense(128)(model)
model = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(model)
model = Flatten()(model)

x1 = Dense(3, activation='softmax',  name='0')(model)
final_model = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=[x1])
final_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer=optimizer,  metrics=['accuracy'])
history = final_model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2, shuffle=False, validation_data=[X_valid, y_valid, valid_weight],  sample_weight=train_weight, callbacks=[Earlystop, checkpoint, Plateau])
```

I thought convolution might be good for this and because every return is calcualted individually I decided to go for a LocallyConnected layer. Do I need to add more layers for such a simple task?

EDIT: transformed my input matrix to returns and the model converges successfully. So the input must be correct but the model fails to find the division function. Are there any layers that would be suited to do that?

Comment: What are the results from your test set?

Comment: It is not converging. Basically it stays at this for all epochs:  `Epoch 5/1000
 - 5s - loss: 12.3980 - acc: 0.5916 - val_loss: 11.8097 - val_acc: 0.5625`

Comment: Not sure here, but some suggestions. Remove Plateau callback and rerun to see if it is causing issues. Also, try generating data similar to inputs to see if it is not a input issue (quality, quantity). You have lots of hyperparameters, try modifying. It is hard to know what is the source of your issues.

Comment: I just transformed the input to match the output by taking the percent change instead of price levels. The model works very nicely now. Hence, the general data should be correct. Do you think LocallyConnected2D makes sense as the first layer?

Comment: It will model filters independently, which assumes weights are independent. Depending on your input context you could also try conv2d layer. I would just try both tbh.